# Ubuntu Apache2 local virtual hosts url not found

Tags: apache, ubuntu, config, local, virtualhost

I am setting up my laptop for single-user development of multiple sites using the LAMP stack on Ubuntu 16.10 with virtual hosts for the different sites, and name-based virtual hosts.  I have tried various combinations of config settings, but I cannot load a site from the Browser, I get "the requested URL was not found on this server."  Here are relevant code snippets from relevant config files:

Ports.conf:

`Listen 8000`

apache2.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:8000
ServerName localhost
...
```

.../sites-enabled/000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
...
```

.../sites-enabled/abc.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
ServerName abc
ServerAdmin admin@abc.com
ServerAlias www.abc.com abc.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/abc
```

.../sites-enabled/pbnat.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:8000>
ServerName pbnat
ServerAdmin admin@pbnat.com
ServerAlias pbnat.com pbn.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/pbnat/public
...
```

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   Lenovo-y2-11
127.0.0.1   abc
127.0.0.1   pbnat
```

Dir Struct:

```
/var/www/
   |-- abc/
       |- index.html
   |-- html/
       |- index.html
   |-- pbnat/
       |-- public/
           |- index.html
```

Permissions on /var/www/:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data julie 4096 Jan  8 16:53 abc
drwxrwxr-x 2 root     root  4096 Dec 31 00:02 html
drwxrwxr-x 3 www-data pbnat 4096 Jan  6 22:32 pbnat
```

Permissions on /var/www/abc/:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data julie 139 Jan  8 16:53 index.html
```

Permissions on /var/www/html/:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root 11321 Dec 31 00:02 index.html
```

Permissions on /var/www/pbnat/:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 www-data pbnat 4096 Jan  7 00:00 public
```

Browser URL tests and results:

file:///var/www/abc/index.html - Success! The abc virtual host is working!

file:///var/www/pbnat/public/index.html - Success! The pbnat virtual host is working!

localhost – site can’t be reached; localhost refused to connect.

localhost:8000 – Apache2 Ubuntu default page

localhost:8000/abc - The requested URL /abc was not found on this server.

localhost:8000/abc.com - The requested URL /abc.com was not found on this server.

- then I changed the IP to 127.0.0.2 in hosts file for the new sites but left localhost as 127.0.0.1 and tried:

127.0.0.2:8000 - Apache2 Ubuntu default page

127.0.0.2:8000/abc – The requested URL /abc was not found on this server.

Error log shows nothing unusual, Access log shows HTTP status code of 404, along with a second code of 495 or 496; also it lists 127.0.0.1 in the first column of the log even if I enter 127.0.0.2:8000/abc

Been going at this quite some time.  Help much appreciated.

Comment: I will recommend you to follow it. Maybe it can help you https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

Comment: @Abbas I did actually heavily reference that tutorial while doing this; I only get the "Success" page by opening the local html file in the browser, can't open it through apache using an IP address or server name/host name.

Comment: There are two things which i notice. There is no sites-available in your question. And second is Your ServerName should be the virtual host name. Like in your case it should be ServerName abc.com

Comment: <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName magento1local.com
        ServerAlias www.magento1local.com
        ServerAdmin webmaster@magento1local.com
        DocumentRoot /home/abbas/www/magento1local.com
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        <Directory "/home/abbas/www/magento1local.com">
           Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
           # changed from None to All
           AllowOverride All
           Order allow,deny
           Allow from all
           Require all granted
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
Above is one of my host.

Comment: @Abbas I am using a2ensite to create the links in sites-enabled from the files in sites-available, just didn't wamt to further clutter my question.  And, I believe that the server names I provided in the VH blocks  match the server names in the hosts file, the .com part is not really necessary in these config directives but I do include them as aliases for completeness.  I will yry the Directory block lines to see ehat effect thst has.  Can you show me your hosts file?

Comment: In the above comment i have added my file content. And it's name is magento1local.com.conf

Comment: @Abbas thank you for your help.  I meant could you share thecontents of your /etc/hosts file, like I show in my question, matching ip addrs to host names on a local machine? I am not setup on a "real" host server, just learning on my laptop offline

Comment: 127.0.1.1       www.magento1local.com
127.0.1.1       magento1local.com

i have added two entries because sometimes visitor can access the site with or without www.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was based in how the URL is entered in the browser.  It should be:
abc:8000
Not:
localhost:8000/abc

Comment: How can we access the virtual hosts from a host machine with apache2 running on Ubuntu-server on a VM-guest (say, VirtualBox)? I have the same situation as above, except that I am not able to access it from the host. I can access the default website with the localhost and port, but not any other websites...