# How to access Virtual Hosts setup on the VM from the Host Machine?

Tags: apache, virtualbox, ubuntu-18.04, ubuntu-server

I want to access my virtual hosts (websites) that I've set up in my VirtualBox -> Ubuntu-Server 18. I have apache2 installed and everything is setup.

The host machine (macOS) can presently gain access to the default website of apache2 in the guest (Ubuntu-server) through a Port Forwarding rule I have assigned in the VirtualBox Network Settings:

`127.0.0.1:8000 -> 10.0.2.15:80`

I've set up a virtual host in my guest machine with the following configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName dropn.taxi
    ServerAdmin admin@dropn.taxi
    DocumentRoot /var/www/dropn.taxi/public_html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

The `DocumentRoot` directory mentioned above exists and has the files necessary to serve a basic "Hello World" home page. I've tested it with my apache installed in my local machine as well. The website's not the problem.

But everytime I access `localhost:8000` from the local machine, I'm greeted with an Ubnutu-Apache greetings page. Whereas when I try `localhost:8000/dropn.taxi`, I get a `404` page. I've researched quite a bit and the closest I can get to a solution is what is suggested in this page:
[Ubuntu Apache2 local virtual hosts url not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41540206/ubuntu-apache2-local-virtual-hosts-url-not-found)

Simply put: How can I access virtual hosts of the guest machine (VM) from the host machine?

Still not specific to my case. Would appreciate any help in this regards.

Answer (score 0):

`localhost` in the apache2 server is set to point to `/var/www/html` by default. For the virtual hosts to work properly, the domain name accessing them must be what is defined in the `ServerName` field.

`localhost:8000/dropn.taxi` would translate to `127.0.0.1/dropn.taxi` in the VM guest. Which means, it is trying to access the `/var/www/html/dropn.taxi`, which, ultimately does not exist, hence the `404` error.

The solution to this is to add `dropn.taxi` to the `/etc/hosts` file in both the Host Machine and the VM. The line would look like:
`127.0.0.1 localhost dropn.taxi`

While accessing from the Host Machine, we use `dropn.taxi:8000` in the browser whereas the port `:8000` is not used in the guest machine. This way, whenever accessing the virtual hosts, the domain name accessing them matches the `ServerName` field and it simply works!